# JSF 2.2: using <h:link> results in slow page (re)load

Tags: jsf-2.2, tomcat8, mojarra

i have a navigation list with pure page-to-page navigation:

```
<h:link outcome="/admin/products"> Products </h:link>
<h:link outcome="/admin/users"> Users </h:link>
<h:link outcome="/admin/markets"> Markets </h:link>
```

the first time i call a page, everything is well. the stuff at the destination-pages with ViewScoped-Beans looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductBean {

   private List<Products>products;
   private int total = 0;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     this.products = Products.getAll();  
   }  

   public void newProduct(){   
      this.total++;
   }       

   public Integer getTotal(){
      return total;
   }
}
```

products.xhtml

```
<h:form id="productForm" prependId="false">

   <h:commandLink value="Add Product" actionListener="#{bean.newProduct}">                             
      <f:ajax render="productsBox" />                                
  </h:commandLink>                            

  <h:panelGroup id="productsBox">
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.total}"/>
  </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

triggering an action at one of the pages, results then in slow page reload when i click on "Products" again or reload the page using F5, or in other words it tooks long time until init() of the ProductBean is called, even when i broke down all logic to a minimal setup like here.

the behaviour seems to be some kind of undefined. sometimes the page-reload is just a bit slower, then very slow or page-load just hangs up.

NOTE: when i replace the h:link with   h:commandLink action="/admin/products"
everything works as "normal". but as i learnt a commandLink is not required here.

what can i do or what is wrong?

using jsf 2.2 and mojarra 2.2.12 and tomcat 8

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't seem to be a general problem with my code. this only happens in firefox and is caused by Firebug Add-on. i didn't find any specific setting there, even re-adding or resetting the plugin didn't solve the problem. but it works when firebug is deactivated.